# Jquery slider -> How to traverse DOM correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My code:

```
<div id = "1">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p class = "V">VVV</p>
    <ul>
        <li>line 1</li>
        <li>line 2</li>
    </ul>
    <p class = "A">AAA</p>
</div>

<div id = "2">
    <h1>Heading 2</h1>
    <p class = "V">VVV</p>
    <ul>
        <li>line 1</li>
        <li>line 2</li>
    </ul>
    <p class = "A">AAA</p>
</div>


$('ul').hide();
$('p.A').hide();
$('p.V').click(function(){
        $(this).next('ul').slideDown('slow');
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).closest('p.A').show(); // <-- How do I select 'p.A' in the current div?    
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S8xcz/7/

This works great up until 'p.V' is hidden. From there, I need to display the 'p.A' (the 'up arrow').

How do I navigate to this?

I'm assuming that hidden elements are still navigable - is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) method goes up the DOM tree to find an ancestor, you probably want to use [`nextAll('p.A')`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll).

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pWDth/

Or [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent) and [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/): `$(this).parent().find('p.A').show();`

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pWDth/1/

Or perhaps [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/): `$(this).siblings('p.A').show();`

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pWDth/2/

I'd probably use `$(this).parent().find('p.A')` as that's the least sensitive to how the HTML is arranged.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(this).closest('p.A').show();
```

with

```
$(this).siblings('p.A:first').show();
```